# Dockerfile - only copy files which match an extension whilst maintaining folder structure

Tags: docker

Suppose I have a very nested folder structure with lots of project files:

```
src
  projectA
    projectA.csproj
    someFile.txt
  projectB
    projectB.csproj
    someFile.txt
  projectC
    projectC.csproj
    someFile.txt
```

In this case I want my DockerFile to copy over the full folder structure, but only include .csproj files:

```
src
  projectA
    projectA.csproj
  projectB
    projectB.csproj
  projectC
    projectC.csproj
```

I can do this for each file line by line, but is there a cleaner way?

```
COPY src/projectA/projectA.csproj src/projectA/projectA.csproj
COPY src/projectB/projectB.csproj src/projectB/projectB.csproj
COPY src/projectC/projectC.csproj src/projectC/projectC.csproj
```

Comment: .dockerignore file I think

Comment: Try RUN instruction in your Dockerfile along with Linux command "cp --parents src/**/*.csproj ." The final command will look like "RUN cp --parents src/**/*.csproj ." use -r flag if needed.

Comment: @VaibhavJain, I'm unable to test your suggestion

Comment: `COPY src/project*/*.csproj src/` but it will not maintain the directory structure

Comment: @Adiii, not only it'll also overwrite the files with the same names

Comment: i did not verify but I thought  a way arround. but you can verify `Add Src/Stock*/*.csproj Src/
RUN ls /app/Src`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've faced a similar situation and the only solution I've found was to prepare a .tgz file containing what I needed and copy it in the docker image using the `ADD` directive.

e.g.
this is a `run.sh` script similar to what I used:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tar cvfz csproj.tgz $( find src -name "*.csproj" )
docker build -t test .
docker run -it --rm test
```

this is a test Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
RUN mkdir /src
ADD csproj.tgz /src
CMD ls -alR /src
```

This solution is not very pleasant but it did do what I needed at the time.

The `ADD` directive (src: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) is able to copy files (like the `COPY` directive) and

> If  is a local tar archive in a recognized compression format (identity, gzip, bzip2 or xz) then it is unpacked as a directory. Resources from remote URLs are not decompressed.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question, but I had the same problem and solved it in a different way:

```
COPY src/*/*.csproj ./
RUN find . -type f -name "*.csproj" -exec sh -c 'export dir_name=$(basename "$1" .csproj); mkdir -p "src/${dir_name}"; mv "$1" "src/${dir_name}/"' shell {} \;
```

I'm creating the folder structure again using `find`. First, I'm getting all the files with the `.csproj` extension and running some commands with `-exec`:

- `export dir_name=$(basename "$1" .csproj)` will create a variable called `dir_name` with the same name of the file but without the extension.
- `mkdir -p "src/${dir_name}"` will create a directory inside `src` with the name from the variable we just created.
- `mv "$1" "src/${dir_name}/"` will move the file we just found inside the directory we just created.

Not pretty, but it works for that case specifically.